# ThunderBolt 3 Dock/Hub on a laptop with USB C (Gen1)

Tags: laptop, docking-station, usb-c, hub

I have a laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad l390) with 2 USB C and wanted to get a  hub that had VGA and RJ-45, and maybe some other ports but most of the options I can find are Thunderbolt 3 Hub/Docks

I was woundering if they will work the same way or not. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same, although they have the same connector.

You can do everything you want with something like this:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ethernet-Adaptor-Samsung-Station-Nintendo-7-1-dex-hub/dp/B07K32NP7X/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=usb+c+hub+vga&qid=1557842509&s=gateway&sr=8-5